# Prevent or postpone commandLink action with yes/no dialog with primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

In my UI there are items edited. In this edit UI the user can switch to the next or previous item. If the user has changed a value (saved in javascript) of the item I want to show a dialog which asks to save and offers the actions "yes", "no" and "cancel".

Here is some example code for the next item link:

```
<p:commandLink ajax="true" action="#{editPropertyBL.nextItem()}" onstart="handleDocNavigation();" process="@this" immediate="true" />
```

Javascript:

```
function handleDocNavigation() {
    if (valueInEditChanged == true) {
        PF('valueChangedEditDialogVar').show();
    } 
}


<p:dialog id="valueChangedEditDialogId" widgetVar="valueChangedEditDialogVar" modal="true">

    <h:outputText value="Save changes?" />

    <f:facet name="footer">
        <h:panelGroup>
            <p:commandButton value="Yes" ...??? />
            <p:commandButton value="No" ...??? />
            <p:commandButton value="Cancel" oncomplete="PF('valueChangedEditDialogVar').hide(); return false;" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </f:facet>
```

The call of editPropertyBL.nextItem() method shall be prevented when the users clicks "cancel" in the confirmation dialog that remains on the current "dirty" item.
When the user clicks "yes" a save action must be invoked (from the confirmation dialog) and then switch to the next item. With "cancel" it is switched to the next item.

Problem is when the modal confirmation dialog is coming up the item is switched before one of the three buttons of the dialog is clicked. I experimented with return false without success.
Any idea how to do that? I think this is common requirement, but haven't found an example.
I think primefaces confirmDialog is not suitable for my case.
Probably remoteCommand could be a solution? I hope there is a more elegant way.

Regards
Oliver

Comment: Why is the confirmDialog not suitable? And why is the combination with the remoteCommand not elegant? If both are not ok, then I think you have to create your own component and 'hack' it into the PF ajax flow/queue. Not sure what is more 'elegant'

Comment: I simply do not know how to do it with the confirmDialog. I checked some further examples and I think it is possible. I will try it... I haven't understood the example in the showcase.

Comment: How do I show the confirmDialog conditionally depending on my value changed javascript variable and postpone or prevent the main action method?

Comment: I think I can use the confirmDialog when I define for each action "next", "previous" and "direct selection" an own confirm dialog.